# Resize Tab size in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Is it possible to reproduce the pin behaviour in term of resizing tabs?
I would like to resize some tabs to have only the icon with no text/title like when pinning a tab.
I've been checking the documentation and I haven't seen anything for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can only pin the tab. Chrome doesn't allow modifying the way its own UI is displayed.

Comment: That makes sense, and probably that's why there's no information about resizing tabs in their documentation.